# Alexa echo cant add a song to a playlist on spotify - Alexa skill builder can be used to add this feature?

Tags: spotify, alexa-skills-kit, playlist

I am trying to add a song to my liked songs playlist and Alexa echo dot says "Sorry, this feature isnt available on Spotify". Can we ourselfs add a feature using aws alexa skill builder or only sptify can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not a supported feature. That said, this is a fantastic idea and if you'd like, as a developer you can submit feature requests and ideas in our uservoice space via the following link:
https://alexa.uservoice.com/